# Gitlab permissions: Wiki only?

Tags: gitlab

Is there a way to grant permission in Gitlab so that a person or role only has access to a Wiki? No issues, no source, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Not quite.

See the [GitLab permissions docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/user/permissions.html).

The lowest level you can assign is **Guest**, which can:

- Create issues
- Download and browse job artifacts.
- View wiki pages

But guest cannot access source code.